# How to add new attribute on reply packet with RADIUS?

Tags: attributes, freeradius

I using the freeradius version is 2.2.8.

I needs new attributes on reply item. So, Added two ATTRIBUTE on "/etc/freeradius/dictionary".

```
ATTRIBUTE  Private-Access-Level      3100  string
ATTRIBUTE  Private-Access-Switch      3100  string
```

And, editing /etc/freeradius/users for test.

```
test  Cleartext-Password := "test"
      Service-Type = Framed-User,
      Private-Access-Level = "userlevel1", 
      Framed-IP-Address = 1.1.1.1,
      Private-Access-Switch = "testRouter",
      Framed-Routing = Broadcast-Listen
```

But, not included Private-xxx attributes in reply packet on captured via wireshark.

I want not use to VSA. could some advise?  plz.

Comment: Could you provide the output of ``radiusd -X`` when sending the test request.

Answer (score 2):

Attributes names map to numbers which have to be able to fit into the RADIUS packet. There is only one byte available for the attribute, so numbers "on the wire" can only be 0-255. Because of this severe limitation, attribute 26 is used as a "Vendor Specific" attribute (VSA) to allow extending the space.

So **you need to either use a VSA, or attributes in the range 1-255**. However, attributes in the standard range are strictly defined in RFCs and by the IETF. There is a small range reserved for experimental use in RFC2865: 192-240, which could potentially be used in a private system. VSA attributes are defined by the organisations owning the relevant Private Enterprise Number.

Essentially, attribute number 3100 is too high and therefore won't ever be able to be coded into a packet and sent on the wire. The documentation in the FreeRADIUS `dictionary` file says this - it can be used for internal purposes only.

Generally speaking however, **you can't just "make up" attributes**. The NAS will have defined attributes that it knows about and is expecting to see in the RADIUS reply, and will ignore all others. So you need to read the NAS documentation to find out what attributes can be sent, and send only those.

As an aside, you have also defined two attributes with the same number. You need to use different numbers for different attributes.